# How do I print this string?

Tags: python

Hi i'm trying to print this string but i get an error.
What is wrong in my code?

```
def main():
    for x in range (0, 100):
        T = 100 - x
        print (T+' bottles of beer on the wall,'+T+'bottles of beer.
        'Take one down, pass it around,'+T-1+' bottles of beer on the wall.')

main()
```

the error is:

```
EOL while scanning the string literal
```

Comment: Rom - you need to tell us what the error that you get is.   By the time you read it and type it in, it might even have told you what the problem is...

Comment: Why don't you count down instead of up? That way you don't have to subtract.

Comment: Fixed the thing up .... why downvote me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things are wrong:

- You forgot to close your string literal; your first line doesn't end with a quote.
- You are trying to concatenate strings and integers. Turn your integers into strings first.
- You are not putting enough spaces into your strings to allow for proper spacing around the numbers.
- You are probably expecting that a newline is going to be included in your output before `Take one down`. You'd have to include an explicit `\n` newline or use separate `print` statements.

Better yet, use the `print` statement built-in capabilities by using commas instead of concatenation:

```
print T, ' bottles of beer on the wall, ', T, ' bottles of beer.'
print 'Take one down, pass it around, ',  T - 1, ' bottles of beer on the wall.'
```

But the best option is to use string formatting:

```
print '{0} bottles of beer on the wall, {0} bottles of beer.'.format(T)
print 'Take one down, pass it around, {0} bottles of beer on the wall.'.format(T - 1)
```

Comment: seems the OP is with py3

Comment: @zhangxaochen: Then why tag it with Python 2.7? Some new users still use parenthesis with the `print` statement, even in Python 2.

Comment: didn't see that.. sorry ;P

Comment: Everything is just fine , but i got banned from posting questions in the site because of 2 people who down voted my questions.. It seems a little absurd. I dont know what to do.... I Can't really help other people because of my lack of knowledge.. I think this site is kind of suppressing new users.
I also have allready fixed the problems with the thread..

Comment: I'd appreciate a re-accept, in the meantime. It feels a little as if you are now punishing those that have helped you with your questions instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `format` function:

```
def main():
    for x in range (0, 100):
        T = 100 - x
        print('{0} bottles of beer on the wall, {0} bottles of beer. '
              'Take one down, pass it around, '
              '{1} bottles of beer on the wall.'.format(T, T-1))
```